# How to assign and manage persistenceid in akka

Tags: persistence, akka

My understanding of the persistenceId in a persistent actor in Akka is that it must have the same value upon reincarnations of the same actor in order to be able to recover state from the persistent store. How would this work in the event of a complete failure of the containing process? Does this mean that the persistenceId of an actor with a known path must be maintained in some other application specific persistent store?

I could understand how this would work with a specific actor with a known path, but how would this work with a worker actor that is controlled by a router pool?

Actors are created and stopped dynamically. How would I be able to associate a durable persistenceId with a specific actor in a router pool and be able to recover the state of the actor in the event of a failure in the containing process.

Comment: Do you plan to have a pool of persistent actors? Would each one be responsible for persisting a different part of the overall state?

Comment: Yes and Yes. Each worker actor in the pool will be working on a separate task submitted by clients to the router pool. The state for each worker will need to persist it's state in order to recover from a failure. The task that a specific worker works on is unrelated to tasks worked on by other workers in the pool.

Comment: Is your pool going to be of fixed size? Otherwise you may have some persisted state for which there is no current worker?

Comment: The pool is not going to be of fixed size. Even in the case of a fixed size there may be persisted state for which there is no current worker. This would happen in the case that the containing operating system process crashes altogether. My question has to do with how to recover persisted state when restarting after an operating system process crash and how does the persistenceId come into play in the case of a varying size router pool.

Comment: OK I see. In cases where there is no pool, it is quite common for the persistence ID to simply be hard coded in the Actor, or passed into the constructor for the actor, so maintaining its value is quite straightforward, even across JVM or OS restarts. I don't think there is a mechanism to help you with exactly what you need, where persistent actors are created dynamically in a pool and the number of them can be variable.